# Dev: non-center backoffice module (top left)

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

always with my module, prestashop 1.6
I have a problem to correctly center and automatically my config page of my module in the admin, everything is displayed except that it is in the top left

```
public function __construct()
{  
    $this->bootstrap = true;

private function _displayForm()
{
    $smarty->assign(array(
    'url' => "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].__PS_BASE_URI__.'/',
    $smarty->display(_PS_MODULE_DIR_ . 'monmodule/option.tpl');
```

option.tpl

```html
<div id="modulecontent" class="bootstrap">
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with

`<div class="panel">`?

EDIT:

Well in my modules I always use the class=""panel" then within you can add a new div with your content and set the div to content="flex" and justify-content="center" along with align-items="center" if necessary.

Comment: yes, no change, https://www.noelshack.com/2019-02-5-1547201401-prestashop-probleme.jpg

Comment: no still does not work
<div class="bootstrap panel" content="flex" id="fieldset_0">
 <div class="panel-heading"><i class="icon-cogs"></i> 
  teste
 </div>
</div>

Comment: I was saying you do this:

` <div class="panel">
    <div class="flex-class">
      your content here
    </div>
</div>`

and the style would be:
`flex-class {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column|row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center
}`

where you choose either the column or the row for the flex-direction directive.
It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

replaces

```html
public function getContent()
{
$this->_displayForm();
```

**replaced by**

```html
public function getContent()
{
 $smarty->assign(array(
 'url' => "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].__PS_BASE_URI__.'/',
 $smarty->display(_PS_MODULE_DIR_ . 'monmodule/option.tpl');﻿
```